# MS Access -- Yes/No statement

Tags: ms-access-2016

I want to create a Yes/No row in a table, the row would be called 'prepayment'. So, if there is one, and you check 'Yes' in the form, I want some textbox to appear -- so you could type in the sum of prepayment. Is there some way to do it the way that textbox to type in the sum wouldn't be visible in the form unless you check 'Yes'?

I didn't really try anything yet. Just have no idea how to do it...

Answer (score 1):

Solomon,

Set the Visible property on the Textbox to No.
Create an On_Click event for the Checkbox.
The code for the On_Click event should change the Textbox Visible property to Yes. You might also want to check the current setting of the Textbox Visible property so you can hide it if they uncheck the Checkbox.